# Is it possible to create an Oracle view with bind variable?

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I tried to create a view (from two different tables) but I want to filter the result placed in my view with a bind variable .

Here's what I've done :

```
dsn_test = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='xxxxxx',port='1521',service_name='trtdiag')
con_test = cx_Oracle.connect(user='rtdiag', password='xxxxx',dsn=dsn_test)

cursor = con_test.cursor()

query = '''
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW INFOS_VEHICLE AS
SELECT IPC_PRESENCE.VEHICLE_ID,IPC_PRESENCE.PRESENT_IWLAN,IPC_PRESENCE.PRESENT_2G3G,RT_SVOI.LAST_SVOI,RT_SVOI.ASSIGNED_DEPOT
FROM IPC_PRESENCE,RT_SVOI
WHERE (IPC_PRESENCE.VEHICLE_ID = RT_SVOI.VEHICLE_ID)
AND (IPC_PRESENCE.VEHICLE_ID = :vehicle)'''

create_view = cursor.execute (query,vehicle=8104)
```

Cx_oracle raises the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_view.py", line 15, in <module>
    create_view = cursor.execute (query,vehicle=8104)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

My question: is it possible to create a view with a bind variable this way or should I do a procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not it is not possible. Instead you would create the view without the last clause, and then do the following in your code:

```
cursor.execute("select * from infos_vehicle where vehicle_id = :vehicle",
        vehicle=8104)
```

Comment: Great! In that case, mark the answer as approved. :-)